# What is project.lock.json?

Tags: .net, .net-core, project.json

I followed the [instruction](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows) to create new .NET Core project and ran this from cmd:

```
dotnet new
dotnet restore
```

The second statement creates `project.lock.json` that contains a lot of garbage (not really garbage but tons of dependencies, configurations etc.). I assume these dependencies is .NET framework that is broken down into separate NuGet packages.

My questions:

1. Is my assumption correct?
2. Can I make my application lighter by removing not needed NuGet packages/dependencies?
3. How?

Comment: Why is this down voted? I believe NuGet is required for .net core apps. Otherwise, you may clone the packages locally and provide your own feed.

Comment: Usually, you don't touch the lock file. You would modify the project.json itself, and the lock file will update itself when you run the tools.

Comment: Your question #2 is a good one and deserves its own SO question in my opinion.

Comment: See Also: [NuGet Docs: Project.json Reference](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/project.json)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**Update**: `project.json` has been replaced with `.csproj` as the main project file for .NET Standard projects. This question refers to the old system before the introduction of [PackageReference in NuGet 4.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files).

You may still occasionally see `project.lock.json` as an artifact of the build process, but it should be ignored. Managing the NuGet packages that your .NET Standard/.NET Core project depends on should always be done by either

- Editing the `.csproj` file directly
- Using the [dotnet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package) (`dotnet add package`, etc)
- Using the Package Manager GUI if you're using Visual Studio

---

**Old answer** for posterity: `project.lock.json` is generated by the .NET tooling when you restore the project's packages. You shouldn't touch it or check it into source control. Edit `project.json` directly.

During the package restore process (`dotnet restore`), NuGet has to analyze the dependencies in your project, walk *their* dependency graphs, and figure out what packages should be installed for your project and your project's dependencies.

This is a non-trivial amount of work, so the results are cached in `project.lock.json` to make subsequent restores faster and more efficient. The lock file will be regenerated if `project.json` is modified and `dotnet restore` is executed again.

Comment: See Also: [NuGet Docs: Project.json Reference](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/project.json)

Comment: We are having very slow build times on Azure Devops. Looking at the logs the nuget restore is taking minutes. There were a couple of articles about using a cache. How do I get my build faster if ideally we shouldn't be doing this anymore?

Answer (score 2):

Every so often, in our team, when someone updates some nuget, we have the same problem, the lock.json files doens't get updated, even running **dotnet restore**  so, before applying the last choice (deleting them) I suggest run **grunt** from your command line.
If that doesn't work, delete all the lock.json files and run **dotnet restore**, this is my favourite choice ;)

Comment: What does grunt have to do with `project.lock.json`?

Comment: don't confuse `package-lock.json` with `project.lock.json`